# How to change AWS spring cloud SQS deletion policy dynamically

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-cloud, amazon-sqs

Currently i have a requirement where we are listening to one SQS but based on the development or testing environment i should change the deletion policy to either on_SUCCESS or NEVER.
Is there any way where we can handle it dynamically . I am using AWS SDK.

```
@SqsListener(value = "${application.marketplace.aws.queueName}", deletionPolicy =SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.NEVER)
    public void pollSQSMsgAscync(final String message) throws Exception {}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by using acknowledgment

```
@SqsListener(value = "${queue.res-notification}", deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.NEVER)
public void receiveMessage(@NotificationMessage String message, @NotificationSubject String subject, Acknowledgment acknowledgment, @Header("ApproximateReceiveCount") final int receiveCount) {
    try {
        if(<some condition>){
            acknowledgment.acknowledge(); // this will delete the message
        }else{
          //do not acknowledge so that message will not be deleted and stays in the queue for new round of reading
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error reading notification ", e);
    }
}
```